# Change data type of a column from object to string in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame my_df:

```
my_df.dtypes

time           int64
fieldA         object
fieldB         object
fieldC         object
fieldD         object
fieldE         object
dtype: object
```

---

I tried to change the fieldB and fieldC to type string by doing:

```
my_df[['fieldB','fieldC']] = my_df[['fieldB','fieldC']].astype(str)
```

After the above is finished, I tried to run `my_df.dtypes` again, but nothing is changed to string ...

Does anyone know what I missed? Thanks!

Comment: they are already strings - `object` is similar to string

Answer (score 1):

Pandas only has a few specific data types that mainly handle numeric values. For everything else it uses the `object` type. Strings fit into the latter category, and so it is likely that your data is already strings, even though the data type is listed as `object`.

The different types are listed in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/basics.html#dtypes):

> The main types stored in pandas objects are `float`, `int`, `bool`,
>   `datetime64[ns]` and `datetime64[ns, tz]` (in >= 0.17.0), `timedelta[ns]`,
>   `category` (in >= 0.15.0), and `object`.